# JFrame hiding windows taskbar when maximized and sets undecorated

Tags: java, swing

I'm having an issue with `JFrame`, when i set my `undecorated = true`, and it's maximized, it turns the `JFrame` to full screen mode, hiding the Windows taskbar. Is there any way to work around it without set `undecorated = false`?

[image]

Comment: `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` will maximize your frame

Comment: I did it, the problem is, the Windows taskbar just disappears when i do that

Comment: Do not set `undecorated = true`

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil well, is there any other way to get the JFrame maximized without the title of window?

Comment: Can you post screen shot of exactly what is happening and tell me if i understand correctly that you want to maximize the Jframe with title bar??

Comment: Maximize without title bar. I can do it when i go home

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil i just put the image

Comment: `undecorated(true);` will remove the titlebar. `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` will make it full screen, but also hide the taskbar. I am sorry I cannot able to help you to get it full screen, but you can use `setSize(width, height)` to set window size manually and `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to display the frame at center of the screen. Not exactly what you want but possible work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative workaround

```
// Gets the screen resolution
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
// Gets the width and height
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
// Subtract height of taskbar from height in my case 50 
frame.setSize((int)width, (int)height - 50);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // Set frame at center of the screen
frame.setUndecorated(true); // Removes title bar
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

### output

[image]

Comment: The only thing i needed to adjust, is to call `setUndecorated` inside frame's constructor, else i got a except